# Can I plug my guitar into my keyboard?

Tags: electric-guitar, keyboard

[image]

My amp just died and I need something to plug my guitar into.

I have and old CASIO CT-700 tone bank keyboard witch has 4 ports:

- MIDI in
- MIDI out
- phones/output
- sustain

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fit a Roland GK3 to your guitar and you can play the keyboard tones via your guitar using Midi.

I realise that's not what you want to achieve, but it's cool none the less!

Answer (score 11):

No, you cannot plug your guitar in this particular keyboard. The Phones jack is a stereo output for headphones, the sustain connector is for a pedal/controller and the midi connectors are for midi control signals to and from an audio interface of some description.

It is possible to connect guitars to some keyboards, as I have utilized this functionality in the past, but they tend to be very expensive keyboards and you're not *really* meant to do it.

You could however invest in an audio interface and plug your guitar into your PC, then use a guitar effects/amp simulation or modeling program. That or invest in a new amplifier.

Comment: To add to Kyle's idea of plugging it into the computer, I believe you could plug it into the microphone jack of the computer.  So you may already have one built in.  Depending on plug size you might need a 1/4 inch to 3.5 mm adapter.

Comment: @jcadcell true, but the sound quality will be horrible.

Comment: If you have an iPhone, or an iPad, or a Mac, there are interfaces that are not so expensive, like the iRig, see http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/cat-view.php?C=interfaces

Comment: If you buy an audio interface, you can use a virtual amp and have excellent quality (with effects, distortions and everything) just by plugging your guitar straight to the audio interface. another thing you can do is use a pedalbord and then plug to the computers microphone (red input) or the blue input (if there is such). The quality will be slightly increased from just plugging to your pc